# Convert text-processing script to web app in Python

Tags: python, web-applications, text-processing

So I have a Python text-processing script, and I need to create a web page with two textareas.

The first one is for data input, and the second one is for (async) on-the-fly displaying the result of passing the data to my script. What is the easiest/fastest way to achive this with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) micro web framework whould be the easiest and fastest.  you could also checkout [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) microwebframework which is pretty much the same idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use lightweight web framework like [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) to create a web server. The server then serves a html that contains some javascript firing AJAX requests containing the data to be processed to your webserver, which in turn responds with the processed data.